# How to add object to array with foreach and switch, case

Tags: php, arrays, object, sum

Hi I wanna ad an object to an array

As you can see below I run through an array and based on the last character i make and switch case, then I wanna construct a new array and add the secon last character to this new array, so I can mannage to sum this new array and print or echo the sum.

```
foreach ($answer as $value) {
  $last=substr($value,-1);
  $score=substr($value,-2,1);
  switch($last){
    case a:
      $a=array();
      array_push($a,$score);
      break;
    case b:
      $b=array();
      array_push($b,$score);
      break;
  }
}
```

In my html table I do this:

```
echo array_sum($a)
```

I can make it work if I add a digit like array_push($a,'2');
but with the object it just overwrite the first one. what do I do wrong here?

Comment: The other syntax issue is that you should be writing `case 'a':` and `case 'b':` instead.

Comment: Quick tip: change `case a:` and `case b:` to `case 'a':` and `case 'b':` The first way causes `Use of undefined constant a - assumed 'a'` warnings.

Answer (score 4):

You're clearing your arrays on every pass. Define them before the foreach loop:

```
$a = array();
$b = array();

foreach ($answer as $value) {
  $last=substr($value,-1);
  $score=substr($value,-2,1);
  switch($last){
    case a:
      array_push($a,$score);
      break;
    case b:

      array_push($b,$score);
      break;
  }
}
```

Comment: So simple...thanks a lot. Its been way too long since I did serious programming! ;o) have a nice weekend

Answer (score 0):

You're creating a new array each time one of those `case` statements matches, which means you're essentially throwing away all the previous times the statement matched, starting from scratch each time. Move the `$a = array()` and `$b = array()` OUTSIDE the loop, so the arrays are created only once:

```
$a = array();
$b = array();
foreach (...) {
   ....
}
```

should fix up the problem